# XML element is not appended - XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to add a new element *iconlink* as a child of each *Layout* element. I am using Xpath expression to select nodes and then Append a child. But every time it is appended to **last** Layout only. 
Can someone help me find out what the issue is. Thanks.

```
        XmlNode newNode = layoutDocument.CreateElement("iconlink");
        XmlAttribute imageAtr = layoutDocument.CreateAttribute("image");
        imageAtr.Value = "CC_Status_Background.png";
        newNode.Attributes.Append(imageAtr);

        var nodeList = layoutDocument.SelectNodes("//Layout[@class]");
        if (nodeList != null && nodeList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                node.AppendChild(newNode);
                layoutModified = true;
            }
        }


       if (layoutModified)
       {
          //Save modified document
       }
```

XML File is as shown

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Layouts layoutid="161">
  <Layout class="1">
    <Page pagenumber="1" name="Page 1" />
    <Page pagenumber="2" name="Page 2" />
    <Page pagenumber="0" name="Page 0">
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128931523" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Favorite.png" required="true" />
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128935340" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Reject.png" required="true" />
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128932676" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Possible.png" required="true" />
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128940983" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Comment.png" required="true" />
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128940984" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Detail.png" required="true" />
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128940982" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Map.gif" required="true" />      
    </Page>   
  </Layout>
  <Layout class="2">
     <Page pagenumber="1" name="Page 1" />
    <Page pagenumber="2" name="Page 2" />
    <Page pagenumber="0" name="Page 0">
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128931523" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Favorite.png" required="true" />
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128935340" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Reject.png" required="true" />
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128932676" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Possible.png" required="true" />
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128940983" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Comment.png" required="true" />
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128940984" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Detail.png" required="true" />
      <iconlink id="iconlink_1262128940982" actionId="" tooltip="" image="CC_Map.gif" required="true" />      
    </Page>   
**<iconlink image="CC_Status_Background.png"></iconlink>**
   </Layout>
</Layouts>
```

Comment: Have you tried for ex. `//Layout[@class='1']`

Comment: Do you insist on using Xpath ? LINQ to XML is so much easier (that is if you are comfortable with LINQ)

Comment: @FrancisDucharme `LINQ to XML` also uses XPath (*xDocument.XPathSelectElement(....)*)

Comment: @L.B Yes with that it is selecting only first layout element

Comment: @PatS And your question?

Comment: I have multiple layout nodes and want to append new element to all of those nodes. current code only appends it to last node.

Comment: @PatS But you create a single instance of `newNode` (single node many parents). How about creating a new one in the loop?

Comment: @L.B is that why just node is being appended that too for the last layout element ? I am trying to create a new node in the loop and see what happens

Comment: Yes you are right. Pardon me for my poor knowledge about XML and DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking of the node as text, but in the DOM the node is a specific instance of an element. You have created a single instance of the element and then you are trying to add it to multiple parents. An XML element can have only one parent, so it looks like your code is just moving it around. Try creating a new instance for each parent:

```
var nodeList = layoutDocument.SelectNodes("//Layout[@class]");
if (nodeList != null && nodeList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        XmlNode newNode = layoutDocument.CreateElement("iconlink");
        XmlAttribute imageAtr = layoutDocument.CreateAttribute("image");
        imageAtr.Value = "CC_Status_Background.png";
        newNode.Attributes.Append(imageAtr);
        node.AppendChild(newNode);
        layoutModified = true;
    }
}
```